# No soy mucho de.... can you say no soy mucha de...?

Tags: gramática, frases-hechas

I know ''No  soy mucho de...''means I am not really interested or into something.

I have looked on various sites like Word Reference but I cannot see if ''no soy mucha de...''exists for females

Is this  a set phrase(frase hecha)? Therefore, in this sense ''mucha''does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "ser mucho de", "mucho" is an adverb and therefore invariable.

This phrase can be followed by nouns or infinitives, the prepositional phrase having adjectival value:

- No soy mucho de las comedias. (not much of a comedy fan)
- No soy mucho de ver comedias. (not very fond of seeing comedies)

Comment: Thank you.That is very clear.